# When function with two tests

Tags: sql, case

I have a question regaring the statement below. As you see the case function test for 1 value.

```
    SUM(case when reknr '8980'   then bdr_hfl * -1 end) as Y,
```

However I would like test for 2 things.

SUM(case (when reknr '8980') and (Dagbk is not null )  then bdr_hfl * -1 end) as Y,

I have tried several option but cannot get the right result.

Thank you for helping.

Add. info. I have tried the option with the place ment of the right brakkets. Unfortunately it does not function. I get a Ambiguous. When I please the GBk. infront of the dagbkrn the code funtion. However I doe not get the right result. It looks like it does not test for the second part.

```
select  GBK.bkstnr_sub as Ordernummer,
        PRP.ParentProject as Project,
            ORK.orddat as Orderdatum,
            ORK.sysguid as OrderGUID,

            ORK.pakbon_dat as OrderAfleverdatum,
            MAX(FHK.fakdat) as Faktuurdatum,

            Datepart(week,(ORK.orddat))as Week,
            ORK.ord_debtor_name as Klant,
            ORK.docnumber,
        SUM(case when (reknr BETWEEN '     8000' AND '     8980') and (dagbknr IS not null) then GBK.bdr_hfl * -1 end) as Omzet,
        SUM(case when reknr BETWEEN '     7000' AND '     7980'  then GBK.bdr_hfl end) as kostprijs,

        (Case when (SUM(case when reknr BETWEEN '     8000' AND '     8980'  then GBK.bdr_hfl * -1 end)) <> 0 then 
        (1-(((SUM(case when reknr BETWEEN '     7000' AND '     7980'  then GBK.bdr_hfl end))/
        (SUM(case when reknr BETWEEN '     8000' AND '     8980'  then GBK.bdr_hfl * -1 end)))))*100 end) as Marge,


        GETDATE() as Datum,
        DATEDIFF(day,GETDATE(),ORK.pakbon_dat) as Dagen
from    [040].dbo.gbkmut as GBK with (nolock)
        left join [040].dbo.orkrg as ORK with (nolock)  on ORK.ordernr = GBK.bkstnr_sub 
        left join [040].dbo.frhkrg as FHK with (nolock) on ORK.ordernr = FHK.ordernr
        left join [040].dbo.PRProject as PRP with (nolock) on PRP.ProjectNr = ORK.projectnr

where   (GBK.dagbknr = 50 or GBK.dagbknr = 40) and ork.ordernr = '15104231' and
        GBK.bkstnr_sub in (
            Select ordernr 
            from [040].dbo.orkrg
            where ord_soort = 'V' and 
                  status = 'A' and 
                  YEAR(orddat)> '2014')
         and ORK.productline is null
         and DATEDIFF(day,GETDATE(),ORK.pakbon_dat) <-45

Group by GBK.bkstnr_sub,PRP.ParentProject,ORK.sysguid,ORK.orddat,ORK.pakbon_dat,Datepart(week,(ORK.orddat)), ORK.ord_debtor_name,ORK.docnumber -- order by Datepart(week,(ORK.orddat))
```

Comment: Have you put an `=` between the `reknr` and `'8980'`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff That wouldn't compile but OP doesn't mention an error but incorrect result, I'm guessing OP forgot to add `else 0` (or whatever it's supposed to be)?

Comment: What result do you have?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN reknr = '8980' AND Dagbk IS NOT NULL  THEN bdr_hfl * -1 END) AS Y
FROM [Insert your table here]
```

Looking at your updated version, I see you try to use between with VARCHAR type. This won't work as you expect it to because it's comparing characters

Consider using this instead :

```
CASE WHEN CONVERT(DECIMAL, ISNULL(reknr, '0')) BETWEEN 8000 AND 8980 THEN GBK.bdr_hfl * -1 END
```

Comment: Updated my answer to handle the case where reknr is null in case it's possible

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for a CASE statement is essentially this:

```
CASE WHEN <condition> THEN <true_value> [ELSE <false_value>] END
```

`<condition>` can be one or more clauses. Your issue is the placement of the brackets, essentially: the first bracketed clause in the condition should not include the WHEN, which is actually part of the syntax for the CASE statement.

Try the following instead:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN (reknr = '8980') AND (dagbk IS NOT NULL) THEN bdr_hfl * -1 END) AS Y,
```